# Angular directive watch height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The question has already been asked but can't make it work properly.

In my directive, using this piece of code works if element's height goes up, but not when going down.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
        return element[0].offsetHeight;
    },
    function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
);
```

edit : the height changes because in the parent controller I use a ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

[working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/x43ZIMBmkZlbsYq6NRkH?p=preview)

make sure calling scope digest when changing the height

```
 $interval(function(){
    height += 10;
    ele.css({height: height + 'px'})
 }, 1000)
```

Comment: on your demo you don't call it.
My height changes because in the controller a ng-repeat is used, sometimes there is nothing so height goes down, sometime there is something so height goes up

Comment: digest is already in progress when I'm changing array used by my ng-repeat